# I'm in the Insider Dev channel, why can't I download the Windows 11 ISO?

Tags: windows, iso-image, windows-insider, windows-11, windows-11-preview

Following the instructions on [TechRadar](https://www.techradar.com/news/how-to-download-windows-11), I joined the Insider program via Setting -> Update & Security -> Windows Insider Program and chose the Dev channel. I can now find the Windows 11 Insider Preview under Windows Update, but that's not what I want to do. I want to download an ISO and install it in a virtual machine.

So again, following the instructions on TechRadar, I went to [this link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewiso). However, I cannot find any ISOs for windows 11, only for Windows 10 ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APqll.png)).

How can I download the Windows 11 ISO?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this guide here - https://nerdschalk.com/how-to-download-windows-11-iso-for-insider-dev-channel-build-yourself/amp/.

It uses software - [UUP Dump](https://uupdump.net/) to download the update from Windows Update and dumps it as an ISO file.

Comment: Not sure, but were you signed in with your Microsoft Account on the website ?

Comment: Yes. Same account that was opted into the Insider Dev channel.

Comment: No idea then...

Answer (score 0):

> I can now find the Windows 11 Insider Preview under Windows Update, but that's not what I want to do. I want to download an ISO and install it in a virtual machine.

The simplest way to avoid substantial problems is to install Windows 10 on the VM then upgrade it to Windows 11.  However, there is a website called [UUP DUMP](https://uupdump.net/), which publishes everything it does on it's GitHub project page [here](https://github.com/uup-dump).

> So again, following the instructions on TechRadar, I went to this link. However, I cannot find any ISOs for windows 11, only for Windows 10 (see screenshot).

Microsoft has not published an ISO for the current Windows 11 Insider Preview at this time.  The page you linked to only applies to Windows 10 at this time.

[Windows 11 Insider Preview 10.0.22000.65 (co_release) amd64](https://uupdump.net/selectlang.php?id=f19ccfd6-d64a-4f0d-8895-c663949fb7e9) will be the closest thing you have to be able to create an ISO yourself. However, there have been problems with weird glitches that have been reported, by installing Windows 11 using this ISO.  Since this is the only method I am aware that actually exists, to create a Windows 11 ISO at this time, if you cannot wait for Microsoft to release an official Windows 11 Insider Preview ISO.

Comment: Due to dynamic nature of the UUP Dump website, you can create virtually any ISO you want, from any build that is released.  I have simply linked to a build that has been released.  If Microsoft released a new build tomorrow you would want to use that instead, due the nature of Insider Preview builds, using the most current build is highly recommended.  *Insider Preview builds typically expire within 6 months.*